# Adding offset and delay

Tags: matlab, time-series, signal-processing, sampling

I have a signal into which I want to introduce several offsets and delays, where offsets range from `0.5` to `5` and delays range from `1` to `7`.

I'm providing an example signal here to demonstrate the problem I'm having, but the size of my real data is 1x1666520.

How do I introduce these changes to the signal?

**Example code:**

```
t  = [ 0 : 1 : 50];           % Time Samples
f  = 45;                      % Input Signal Frequency
Fs = 440;                     % Sampling Frequency
data = sin(2*pi*f/Fs*t)'; 

T.InputOffset = 5;
T.OutputOffset = 5;

addoffset = retrend(data);
Y = step(delay,data);

figure(); plot(t,addoffset,t,Y);
```

Comment: Next time, please specify the error/problem you're getting in the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot and sure next time I will also attach the type of error that I am getting in question

Comment: Dev-iL can you please have a look at the latest issue.

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. If you have a new problem, you should open a new question and provide a link to this one for reference. After you create the new question, your last edit should be rolled back.

Comment: Dev-iL I thought that it will become a repeated question so thats why did not made a new qurrey.

Comment: When you make the new question, add the minimum code required to reproduce the problem ([mcve]). If you do that, it will not be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Dev-iL i have made a new thread . Have a look at that one also .Link is as follows  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45941060/error-using-iddata-for-system-identification-toolbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to run your example code, I'm getting this error:

> Undefined function `retrend` for input arguments of type `double`.

The cause of this is that the [`retrend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/retrend.html) function, which is part of the [System Identification Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/index.html), requires a [data object (`iddata`)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/iddata.html) as an input.

If you have the aforementioned toolbox, you can create a data object as in the [example for `retrend`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/retrend.html#examples), then add a **trend** similarly to what you already tried.

To my understanding, adding a **delay** is trickier, because you need to maintain the same vector length. You can pad your vectors with some dummy values (such as `NaN`) in the correct direction.

Applied to your case we get:

```
function q45688607
%% Generate data:
t  = (0 : 1 : 50).';       % Time Samples
f  = 45;                   % Input Signal Frequency
Fs = 440;                  % Sampling Frequency
y = sin(2*pi*f/Fs*t); 
d_data = iddata(y, t, 1/Fs);

%% Add offset:
T = getTrend(d_data); 
% <detrend data if needed>
T.InputOffset = 5;
T.OutputOffset = 5;
afterOffset = retrend(d_data,T);

%% Add delay: 
delaySamples = 8; % Must be a non-negative value
afterDelay = iddata([NaN(delaySamples,1); d_data.OutputData],...
                    [d_data.InputData; NaN(delaySamples,1)], 1/Fs);    
%% Plot:
figure(); plot(d_data,afterOffset, afterDelay);
```

Yielding:

[image: After adding a trend + offset]

Comment: Thanks a lot Dev-iL This is the perfect answer which I was looking for just wondering if I want to make this for different sets of offset and delay values