# Undefined function 'minus' for input argument of type 'iddata'

Tags: matlab, methods, time-series, signal-processing, sampling

This is a followup to [a previous issue I was having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688607).

I want to give an offset to a signal then add some delay in it and calculate RMSE for that but when taking difference I am having the following issue:

[image]

I would like to ask the following things:

1. How can I solve the above problem?
2. Will anybody please explain in simple words what `iddata` does - because I have studied different portals including MATLAB but remained unable to get a good concept.
3. How can I store data of type `iddata` in cell for subtraction in the last part of my code?

#### Code with Problem :

```
 drv(1)=load('123.mat');

 t = drv(1).x;
 ref = drv(1).y;
 angle = drv(1).z;
 Fs = 1000;              
 t1 =t';
 ref1= ref';
 d_data = iddata(ref1, t1, 1/Fs);

 %% Add offset:
 x = 1;
 afterOffset1= {};
 for i = 100:10:130 
 T = getTrend(d_data); 
 % <detrend data if needed>
 T.InputOffset = i;
 T.OutputOffset = i;
 afterOffset = retrend(d_data,T);
 afterOffset1{x,1}= afterOffset;
 x= x+1 ;
 end 

 %% Add delay:
 y=20;
 afterDelay1= {};
 for i = 1:1:4
 % delaySamples = i; % Must be a non-negative value
 % afterDelay = iddata([NaN(delaySamples,1); d_data.OutputData],...
 %                     [d_data.InputData; NaN(delaySamples,1)], 1/Fs);
 afterOffset1{i}.Tstart = y;
 afterDelay1{i,1}= afterOffset1{i};
 y= y+10;
 end 
 %% Plot:
 n = size(afterDelay1,1);
 figure();
 for i=1:1:n
 subplot(2,2,i);

 plot(d_data);
 hold all
 plot(afterDelay1{i});
 end

 sig_diff = angle(1)-afterDelay1;
 square_error(i,:) = (sig_diff(i)).^2;
 mse(i,:)=  mean(square_error(i));
 rmse(i,:) = sqrt(mse(i));


 sig_diff = d_data_1 - afterDelay; %        <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Problem is here
 %     square_error = (sig_diff).^2;
 %     mse=  mean(square_error);
 %     rmse = sqrt(mse);
 end
```

Comment: rayryeng I have installed the system identification tool box . I have problem in this line sig_diff = angle(1)-afterDelay1; actually I want to subtract iddata from matrix this could be an issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dev-iL for editing my problem.

Comment: I misread the problem. Apologies. I've created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want the `OutputData` attribute from the `iddata` object which is the output or `y` signal of your problem:

```
sig_diff = angle(1)-afterDelay1.OutputData;
```

Also note that this will give you a **column** vector, but your code later on assumes it's a row vector.  You may want to transpose this data after you perform the above calculation before proceeding:

```
sig_diff = angle(1)-afterDelay1.OutputData;
sig_diff = sig_diff.';
```

In general, `iddata` is a function that creates an object that represents input and output time or frequency domain data.  Take note that when you create an `iddata` object, the input matrix can potentially have multiple sources and so each **column** dictates a source.  The same can be said for the output where each **column** dictates an output.  Therefore, it is very important that you transpose your data prior to using this function to ensure that each signal is in a separate column, or just use a single column to represent one input / output.

Inside the object has a variety of attributes, including the sampling time or sampling frequency, the valid domain and range that the function takes on and finally accessing the input and output data.  `OutputData` is one of these fields.  I'd recommend looking at the documentation that talks about all of the attributes that you can access with `iddata`.  `OutputData` is clearly defined here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/iddata.html

Comment: rayryeng . Thanks a lot it worked great for me  and also thanks to you for ur explanation regarding iddata . Its good explanation for beginners like me with system identification tool box.

Comment: Just one question how outdata = afterDelay1.OutputData . When I use this command it converts 3D data into 2D i am confused how it is done as outdata should also contain 3D  . Can you resolve my this confusion also please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Peter I'm not quite sure I follow.  I didn't realize your input was 3D data.  Could you give me more information on what your input and output data looks like?  Better yet, I'd love it if you could upload a copy of your MAT file so I can see for myself.  I can modify my post more easily as I will be able to run your code above.

Comment: First of all really sorry for  a bit late reply. Actually I am unable to upload original data so thats why i tried to ask the qurrey by making an example .3D means or may be i am confused here as I have data of 166230*1*1 in afterDelay1 so how i will get 166230*1 in outdata when I perform this command outdata = afterDelay1.OutputData .Sorry for inconvenience in advance.

Comment: Trailing singleton dimensions on a matrix don't exist in MATLAB. Do you mean that it's a 1 x 1 x 166230 matrix?

Comment: rayryeng really sorry my mistake I got it. Thanks a lot for such a great help and support.